# Build a tile-based map in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

```
var square:Sprite = new Sprite();

var tileWidth:int = 32;
var tileHeight:int = 32;

    var row:int = 0;

    for (var i:int=0;i<5;i++) {

        if (i > 0)
        {
            row = 32 * i;
        }

    square.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    square.graphics.drawRect(row,0,32,32);
    square.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(square);

    }
```

This is my code so far, is square.graphics the way to go? How do I draw a tile that is a picture? Do I need to hold the graphics in some sort of array to do checking like collision?

Comment: I'm not a game developer by any means so I don't feel comfortable posting this as an answer but my thought is you would want to have a sprite that holds all the tiles, in that sprite you would want to set the position based on the row/column as opposed to offsetting the drawing within each sprite.  This way you can use the x,y,width,height, of each tile sprite within the "map" sprite to do collision detection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to desire any performance out of this, you need to look at things like blitting - or copying pixel data from a source image to single display object in this case.  So you make a crazy image with all your tiles on it.  Then your blit engine  copies specific boxes of the image representing that tile to a specific place in the larger display object.

Google - as3 blitting - or check out http://freelanceflashgames.com/news/2010/02/08/bold-pixel-engine-an-as3-framework-for-games/